# Output of bash script is going to another putty session

Tags: linux, bash, session, terminal, putty

I have a script as below, when I am running this script in the 1st putty session. The output of script is displayed on the 1st putty session. If I open another (2nd) putty session and run the same script on 2nd putty session, still the output goes to the old putty (1st) session.

```
echo "*******Output command $args starts ***********"
pf=`oprmsg 'VARY CN(*),ACTIVATE'`
echo $pf
sleep 1
echo `oprmsg "$@"`
sleep 7
echo `oprmsg 'VARY CN(*),DEACTIVATE'`
sleep 1
echo "******* Output of command $args ends *************"
```

any idea why?

Comment: are you using screen or tmux ?

Comment: I am using putty terminal..I am not sure what is tmux?